# Schema-binding with recursive scalar UDF

Tags: sql-server, functions, recursive

**TL;DR;** **Is it a bug** that SQL Server allows a scalar UDF to recursively call itself when schema-bound, but only when altered to do so using the `CREATE OR ALTER` syntax? Or is it a bug that other syntaxes are disallowed?

---

A trivial recursive scalar UDF can be constructed as follows

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Try1 (@i int)
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN
  RETURN IIF(@i = 0, 0, @i + dbo.Try1(@i - 1));
END;
```

As long as this is not schema-bound then this is allowed.

---

Let's try schema-binding it, we'll do

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Try2 (@i int)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN
  RETURN IIF(@i = 0, 0, @i + dbo.Try2(@i - 1));
END;
```

Nope.

```
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function
or aggregate "dbo.Try2", or the name is ambiguous
```

---

Create it without recursion then alter it

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Try3 (@i int)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN RETURN NULL; END;
```

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Try3 (@i int)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN
  RETURN IIF(@i = 0, 0, @i + dbo.Try3(@i - 1));
END;
```

A different error this time:

```
Cannot schema bind function 'dbo.Try3' because name 'dbo.Try3' is invalid
for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format
and an object cannot reference itself.
```

Hmmm, `an object cannot reference itself` who invented that rule? **It's not in the docs.**

---

Let's try with `CREATE OR ALTER`

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Try4 (@i int)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN
  RETURN IIF(@i = 0, 0, @i + dbo.Try4(@i - 1));
END;
```

Still not.

---

But if we *first* do `CREATE` *without* recursion, then do `CREATE OR ALTER` (*not* `ALTER`) with recursion then it works

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Try5 (@i int)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN RETURN NULL; END;
```

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Try5 (@i int)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN
  RETURN IIF(@i = 0, 0, @i + dbo.Try5(@i - 1));
END;
```

---

The weird thing is: this doesn't make sense whichever way `CREATE OR ALTER` works underneath. If it actually drops and re-creates then why don't we get the first error? And if it alter then why does this last option work?

The funniest bit: If we create it without schema-binding first, then do `CREATE OR ALTER WITH SCHEMABINDING` then we get

```
Cannot schema bind function 'dbo.Try6'. 'dbo.Try6' is not schema bound.
```

Which is just utter nonsense.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/greCS78B)

Comment: With call stacks of errors added https://dbfiddle.uk/EH58sz-F `CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Try5` does still go to `sqllang.dll!ValidateObjForSchemaBinding` in the same way as `ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Try3` does but doesn't throw the error.

Comment: That's interesting. Shame we can't get the full source code. What was the stack for `Try6`?

Comment: Try6 is thrown from `sqllang.dll!ValidateObjForSchemaBinding()` again https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljWLO.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Self-referencing functions are not well documented in general, but the restriction on schema-binding such functions has been around forever. Not every error condition is mentioned in the parent syntax pages.

The particular sequence of events outlined in the question that results in a schema-bound self-referencing function should **not** be allowed. (It works for multi-statement table-valued functions as well).

Allowing schema-binding for self-referencing functions introduces many new possibilities which would have to be considered and tested. For example, the following use of your function results in a `DBCC CHECKTABLE` failure:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test 
(
    n integer NOT NULL,
    -- Can be persisted because the function is deterministic
    -- Checks for determinism require schemabinding
    sn AS dbo.Try5(n) PERSISTED, 
        CHECK (sn > 0)
);

-- Succeeds
INSERT dbo.Test (n) 
VALUES (31);

DBCC CHECKTABLE (N'dbo.Test') 
    WITH EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS;
```

```
Msg 2537, Level 16, State 0, Line 76
Table error: object ID 1137439126, index ID 0, partition ID 72057594050772992,
alloc unit ID 72057594110541824 (type In-row data), page (1:568), row 0.
The record check (valid computed column) failed. The values are 2 and 0.
DBCC results for 'Test'.
There are 1 rows in 1 pages for object "Test".
CHECKTABLE found 0 allocation errors and 1 consistency errors in table 'Test'
 (object ID 1137439126).
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by
 DBCC CHECKTABLE (Sandpit.dbo.Test).
DBCC execution completed. 
If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

I didn't look into the reasons for this failure, but I suppose the `CHECKTABLE` activity to verify the computed column value ends up exceeding the maximum nesting level of 32.

Many things would need testing and/or tweaking to support schema-binding self-referencing functions. This usage isn't popular enough to justify the investment. Alternatives for recursion exist within SQL Server.